# Extract words in a paragraph that are similar to words in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, difflib

I have the following string:

```
"The boy went to twn and bought sausage and chicken. He then picked a tddy for his sister"
```

List of words to be extracted:

```
["town","teddy","chicken","boy went"]
```

NB: town and teddy are wrongly spelt in the given sentence.

I have tried the following but I get other words that are not part of the answer:

```
import difflib

sent = "The boy went to twn and bought sausage and chicken. He then picked a tddy for his sister"

list1 = ["town","teddy","chicken","boy went"]

[difflib.get_close_matches(x.lower().strip(), sent.split()) for x in list1 ]
```

I am getting the following result:

```
[['twn', 'to'], ['tddy'], ['chicken.', 'picked'], ['went']]
```

instead of:

```
'twn', 'tddy', 'chicken','boy went'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice in the documentation for [`difflib.get_closest_matches()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.get_close_matches):

> `difflib.get_close_matches(word, possibilities, n=3, cutoff=0.6)`
>
> Return a list of the best "good enough" matches. `word` is a sequence for which close matches are desired (typically a string), and
> `possibilities` is a list of sequences against which to match `word`
> (typically a list of strings).
>
> Optional argument `n` (default `3`) is the maximum number of close matches to return; `n` must be greater than `0`.
>
> Optional argument `cutoff` (default `0.6`) is a float in the range `[0, 1]`. Possibilities that don’t score at least that similar to word are
> ignored.

---

At the moment, you are using the default `n` and `cutoff` arguments.

You can specify either (or both), to narrow down the returned matches.

For example, you could use a `cutoff` score of 0.75:

```
result = [difflib.get_close_matches(x.lower().strip(), sent.split(), cutoff=0.75) for x in list1]
```

Or, you could specify that only at most 1 match should be returned:

```
result = [difflib.get_close_matches(x.lower().strip(), sent.split(), n=1) for x in list1]
```

In either case, you could use a list comprehension to flatten the lists of lists (since `difflib.get_close_matches()` always returns a list):

```
matches = [r[0] for r in result]
```

---

Since you also want to check for close matches of bigrams, you can do so by extracting pairings of adjacent "words", and pass them to `difflib.get_close_matches()` as part of the `possibilities` argument.

Here is a full working example of this in action:

```
import difflib
import re

sent = "The boy went to twn and bought sausage and chicken. He then picked a tddy for his sister"

list1 = ["town", "teddy", "chicken", "boy went"]

# this extracts overlapping pairings of "words"
# i.e. ['The boy', 'boy went', 'went to', 'to twn', ...
pairs = re.findall(r'(?=(\b[^ ]+ [^ ]+\b))', sent)

# we pass the sent.split() list as before
# and concatenate the new pairs list to the end of it also
result = [difflib.get_close_matches(x.lower().strip(), sent.split() + pairs, n=1) for x in list1]

matches = [r[0] for r in result]

print(matches)
# ['twn', 'tddy', 'chicken.', 'boy went']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you read Python documentation fordifflib.get_close_matches()
https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html
It returns all possible best matches.
Method signature:
difflib.get_close_matches(word, possibilities, n=3, cutoff=0.6)

Here n is the maximum number of close matches to return. So I think you can pass this as 1.

```
>>> [difflib.get_close_matches(x.lower().strip(), sent.split(),1)[0] for x in list1]
['twn', 'tddy', 'chicken.', 'went']
```